# How to define the routes?

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to NodeJs and Express. I want to make an `Ajax` call from an `ejs` file :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      async : false,
      url: "/organisation/list",
      success : function(data, status, xhr) {
        alert("finsihed");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the config of my app :

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the index.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

How to make it possible to reach the Ajax url `/organisation/list` ? Should I create another file in the `routes` directory ?

Comment: `Should I create another file in the routes directory` yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can simply write a route like this :***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


/* GET organisation list. */
router.get('/organisation/list', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });


module.exports = router;
```

***or you can create a separate file that handles all requests related to the organization.***

> app.js

```
app.use('/organization', require('./routes/organization.js');
```

> routes/organization.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/list', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  res.status(200).json([]);
});

module.exports = router;
```